# Reset seekbar to beginning on back activity

Tags: android

I have a seekbar in my activity. In the button event when I go to another activity and then use back button, the values of the seekbar are set where the user left it. I would like to reset the seekbar when the user comes back to the seekbar activity. How can I achieve it? Thanks

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (seek.getProgress > 0) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

simply reset the seek bar in `onPause` or `onResume` of your `SeekBarActivity`, i.e. :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    seek.setProgress(0);
    super.onPause();
}
```

This will be called when you have started another activity and the current one is paused.